# iOS 14 clock widget freeze everyday at 11:59

Tags: ios, time, widget, clock

My widget clock **freezes** every day at **11:59 mid-night**.

below is my `TimelineProvider` code.

```
private struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: Date())
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(date: Date())
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
        var entries = [SimpleEntry]()
        let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
        let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!

        for offset in 0 ..< 60 * 24 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: offset, to: midnight)!
            entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate))
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .after(nextMidnight))
        completion(timeline)
    }
}
```

Does anyone also face this issue?

Comment: Seems the last entry is 23:59 of the current day.

Comment: yes, but is there a way we can restart entry at 23:59 every day?

Answer (score 0):

Use this modified code

```
    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> Void) {
    var entries = [SimpleEntry]()
    let midnight = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
    let nextMidnight = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: midnight)!

    for offset in 1 ... 60 * 24 {
        let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: offset, to: midnight)!
        entries.append(SimpleEntry(date: entryDate))
    }

    let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
    completion(timeline)
}
```